# Wireguard connectivity between handshakes

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

I've been having this really weird issue. I'm running WG on a VPS and on my macbook.
I run WG on the linuxserver container on a debian host.
The connection is great, the speed is good, everything works really well.
I've noticed though that every once in a while (like every 10-20min) there will be a handshake and my connection to the internet instantly drops. I can still access internal services so I know my macbook is still connected to the server. I can't access the internet for 16seconds until the next handshake when the internet instantly comes back.

I've monitored the server during this and I can see that while downloading a torrent there's a lot of `kworker/1:1-wg-crypt-wg0` processes running and when this happens all of these processes are killed. It's almost as if the server is being restarted or WG is being restarted, but I know that's not the case because I can still access internal containers so the connection is there and WG didn't go down.

I know for a fact that I still have internet on other devices so it has something to do with wireguard.

This happens regardless of whether I'm doing intense networking like downloading a torrent or just browsing the web.
It looks like it's not the VPS losing connection. I've been pinging google and when it happens the VPS keeps pinging google and my macbook can't ping google

I'm looking for help on what it could be and what I should look into and how I can approach this... could it be something related to my router? Could it be a config issue?

Here are my configs:

**Server**

```
   [Interface]

   # Core settings
   PrivateKey = xxxxx
   Address = 10.6.0.0/24

   # Misc. settings (optional)
   ListenPort = 51820

   # Interface hooks (optional)
   PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
   PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE

   MTU = 1400

   #
   # Peers
   #

   [Peer]
   PublicKey = xxxxx
   PresharedKey = xxxx
   AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
   PersistentKeepalive = 16
```

**MACBOOK**

```
   [Interface]

   # Core settings

   PrivateKey = xxxxx
   Address = 10.6.0.2/32

   # Misc. settings (optional)
   DNS = xxxxx

   MTU = 1400

   [Peer]
   PublicKey = xxxx
   Endpoint = xxxx:51820
   AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.1/32, 0.0.0.0/0
   PresharedKey = xxxx
   PersistentKeepalive = 16
```

UPDATE:

These are the logs I get on the server side with `modprobe wireguard`.

```
Mar 16 13:55:54 [  +2.156106] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 315 (<my-client-ip>:16235)
Mar 16 13:55:54 [  +0.000003] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 315 (<my-client-ip>)
Mar 16 13:55:54 [  +0.000165] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10604 destroyed for peer 315
Mar 16 13:55:54 [  +0.000002] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10606 created for peer 315

Mar 16 13:56:10 [  +2.451426] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 315 (<my-client-ip>)
Mar 16 13:56:10 [  +0.000003] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 315 (<my-client-ip>)
Mar 16 13:56:10 [  +0.000185] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10605 destroyed for peer 315
Mar 16 13:56:10 [  +0.000001] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10607 created for peer 315
Mar 16 13:56:10 [  +0.161195] wireguard: wg0: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 315 (<my-client-ip>)
```

And from the client side, pinging google.com to check internet connection

```
Mar 16 10:55:54 64 bytes from <google-ip>: icmp_seq=187 ttl=108 time=161.723 ms
Mar 16 10:55:56 Request timeout for icmp_seq 188
Mar 16 10:55:57 Request timeout for icmp_seq 189
Mar 16 10:55:58 Request timeout for icmp_seq 190
Mar 16 10:55:59 Request timeout for icmp_seq 191
Mar 16 10:56:00 Request timeout for icmp_seq 192
Mar 16 10:56:01 Request timeout for icmp_seq 193
Mar 16 10:56:02 Request timeout for icmp_seq 194
Mar 16 10:56:03 Request timeout for icmp_seq 195
Mar 16 10:56:04 Request timeout for icmp_seq 196
Mar 16 10:56:05 Request timeout for icmp_seq 197
Mar 16 10:56:06 Request timeout for icmp_seq 198
Mar 16 10:56:07 Request timeout for icmp_seq 199
Mar 16 10:56:08 Request timeout for icmp_seq 200
Mar 16 10:56:09 Request timeout for icmp_seq 201
Mar 16 10:56:10 Request timeout for icmp_seq 202
Mar 16 10:56:11 Request timeout for icmp_seq 203
Mar 16 10:56:11 64 bytes from <google-ip>: icmp_seq=204 ttl=108 time=161.172 ms
```

so there are two successful handshakes, but in between them I can't access the web

UPDATE 2:

Managed to get some level of logging on the client side (macbook). By running

```
sudo LOG_LEVEL=verbose wg show
```

I'm getting logs on when the macbook is receiving handshake responses and initiating handshakes.

In this new example the server
logs:

```
~INTERNET GOES DOWN HERE~
Mar 16 16:47:09 [  +0.393175] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 315 (<client-ip>)
Mar 16 16:47:09 [  +0.000003] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 315 (<client-ip>)
Mar 16 16:47:09 [  +0.000175] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10790 destroyed for peer 315
Mar 16 16:47:09 [  +0.000001] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10793 created for peer 315
Mar 16 16:47:09 [  +0.280476] wireguard: wg0: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 315 (<client-ip>)

~INTERNET GOES BACK UP RIGHT AFTER THE NEXT LINES~

Mar 16 16:47:25 [  +1.391045] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 315 (<client-ip>)
Mar 16 16:47:25 [  +0.000003] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 315 (<client-ip>)
Mar 16 16:47:25 [  +0.000166] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10792 destroyed for peer 315
Mar 16 16:47:25 [  +0.000002] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10794 created for peer 315
Mar 16 16:47:25 [  +0.159758] wireguard: wg0: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 315 (<client-ip>)
```

On the client side I see

```
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:42:35 peer(xxxx) - Received handshake response
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:42:35 peer(xxxx) - Sending keepalive packet
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:44:35 peer(xxxx) - Sending handshake initiation
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:44:35 peer(xxxx) - Received handshake response
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:44:35 peer(xxxx) - Sending keepalive packet
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:46:35 peer(xxxx) - Sending handshake initiation
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:46:35 peer(xxxx) - Received handshake response
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:46:35 peer(xxxx) - Sending keepalive packet
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:47:24 peer(xxxx) - Retrying handshake because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:47:24 peer(xxxx) - Sending handshake initiation
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:47:24 peer(xxxx) - Received handshake response
DEBUG: (utun6) 2023/03/16 13:47:24 peer(xxxx) - Sending keepalive packet
```

I find the `Retrying handshake because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds` interesting cause that's when the internet goes down. So handshake fails and client retries and then it works? But why?

UPDATE:

I see that there's something going on with the faulty handshake port.

I have a `watch wg show all` in the server and I can see that my macbook peer config is `<my-ip>:16918`. Whenever a handshake fails and I lose connection I see a log like this on the server side:

```
Mar 16 18:17:19 [  +1.217668] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 318 (<client-ip>:16235)
Mar 16 18:17:19 [  +0.000004] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 318 (<client-ip>:16235)
Mar 16 18:17:19 [  +0.000191] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10893 destroyed for peer 318
Mar 16 18:17:19 [  +0.000002] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10896 created for peer 318
Mar 16 18:17:19 [  +0.275182] wireguard: wg0: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 318 (<client-ip>:16235)




Mar 16 18:17:34 [  +0.687921] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 318 (<client-ip>:16918)
Mar 16 18:17:34 [  +0.000004] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 318 (<client-ip>:16918)
Mar 16 18:17:34 [  +0.000250] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10894 destroyed for peer 318
Mar 16 18:17:34 [  +0.000002] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 10897 created for peer 318
Mar 16 18:17:34 [  +0.164268] wireguard: wg0: Receiving keepalive packet from peer 318 (<client-ip>:16918)
```

For some reason the handshake is coming from a different port and so the server responds to the same port, but the client isn't listening on that port

Comment: What do the Wireguard module [logs](https://serverfault.com/a/1020299/5799) tell you, on both the client and server?

Comment: @user1686 I've edited the main question with server side logs. Still trying to figure out how to do that on the mac

Comment: On macOS, wireguard is not a kernel module so the logs will be somewhere within the app instead (as well as being different overall).

Comment: @user1686 yeah I've been trying to find where these logs are stored, but it's proving to be really hard to find. Do you have any idea just by looking at the server side logs?

Comment: No; can you run a packet capture to check whether the server at least keeps receiving the WireGuard packets from the client when its connection dies? (Both on the physical interface, and on the wg0 interface.)

Comment: @user1686 I'm pretty sure the connection doesn't die since I can still access and see logs for internal services in that 16 seconds window. I added logs from the client side. It looks like the handshake times out from the client POV for some reason

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295086/963426) that might relate your case, and especially its advice to use PreUp and PreDown rather than PostUp and PostDown.

Comment: Yes sorry @harrymc. Editting my answer now

Comment: In "Update 2", the server receives a handshake and keepalive at 16:47:09, but the client logs do not show a handshake at 13:47:09. If this is accurate (assuming handshakes are not susceptible to replay attacks), it suggests a second instance of WireGuard on port 16235 that is messing things up, or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried everything in this thread and nothing seemed to really change the issue. In the end I reverted back to the config that I show in the original post and after a while the issue went away. I believe it might have something to do with the ISP or the ISP's router that I'm using. I didn't do any changes... maybe the electricity went out and restarting the router did it, but I don't know.

The answers are still useful so make sure to follow them if you're having the same issue and I suggest give it a try at a friend's house to see if it persists

Comment: Which thread..?

Comment: @Greenonline both replies to the main post as well as to the one that was awarded the bounty

Comment: I see - confusing terminology... I think you mean the *comments* (not "replies") under the question, and the *answer* with the bounty. I was confused when you said "thread" as that implies a link to an external forum (and that link was missing). Stack Exchange is *not* a forum of threads and threaded messages and "replies" - it is a Q&A site. It might seem pedantic, but if you refer to threads (when you mean this page with its question and associated answers) then you will end up confusing people.

Comment: I have the same experience, restart the router works, the SYMPTOM is wireguard handshake normally for about 92 bytes then stop

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to make sure is: is there another device with the same client profile. (another computer, phone)
If so, even if it is supposed to be sleeping, it most probably is the issue, so configure another profile for this device.

The second point is: you have a timeout at 15s and a keepalive at 16s. Could you try to lower the keeapalive at 14s (or less) to see if it solves the problem?

Then, there are some issues in your configuration, it might not be related, but it would be better to fix them to be sure.

1. In the server configuration, in the `[interface]` block, the `Address` parameter is `10.6.0.0/24`. It should be `10.6.0.1/24` instead: 10.6.0.0/24 is the subnet address and cannot be use. There might be an error in the client installed route then.
2. In the client configuration, in the `[peer]` block, the `AllowedIPs` parameter has both "all" (0.0.0.0/0) and an IP address (10.6.0.1/32). You should have `0.0.0.0/0` only, or multiple IP address / subnets but not `0.0.0.0/0`.
   If you have only `0.0.0.0/0`, wireguard will setup an exclusion route for your endpoint IP address.
   If you have multiple `AllowedIPs`, you have to make sure none of the subnets are matching your endpoint IP address.
   You have multiple entry, including `0.0.0.0/0`, it is possible that wireguard doesn't make the exclusion, but `0.0.0.0/0` does include your endpoint IP address.